# MySecureShell SFTP "Authentication Failed"

Tags: ssh, sftp

I am trying to connect to my SFTP server (Configured with MySecureShell), but keep getting the response "Authentication Failed". The username and password is correct.

I created an SFTP group:

```
groupadd sftp
```

Then made a user for that group with the shell:

```
useradd WebFiles -m -s /usr/bin/MySecureShell -g sftp
```

And gave him a password

Then appended the `/etc/ssh/sftp_config` file with:

```
<Group sftp>
    Download                0       
    Upload                  0       
    StayAtHome              true    
    VirtualChroot           true    
    LimitConnectionByUser   10      
    LimitConnectionByIP     10      
    IdleTimeOut             300     
    HideNoAccess            true    
</Group>
```

But it wont let me connect

My final aim is to have the user `WebFiles` to have access to the `/var/www` directory, but first I just need to get him to be able to connect Lol

Any help appreciated :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add the home path here :

```
Home /var/www/

Download                0       
Upload                  0       
StayAtHome              true    
VirtualChroot           true    
LimitConnectionByUser   10      
LimitConnectionByIP     10      
IdleTimeOut             300     
HideNoAccess            true
```

Tell me if that works.